# Strange, Sudden compiler fail error in Xcode for iPhone dev

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction

What is the following error caused by? I did not make any significant changes and suddenly it started appearing:

```
Linking /Users/JimB/Desktop/iPhone Dev/Games4Kids/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ETFanClub.app/Games4Kids(1 error)



duplicate symbol .objc_category_nameNSString_HTTPExtensions in (path)ViewController3 and (path)ViewController1



Command /Xcode 3.1.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Post the whole error message please.

Comment: Ok I posted the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol `.objc_category_nameNSString_HTTPExtensions` is duplicated, meaning the category `NSString(HTTPExtensions)` is declared twice `ViewController3` and `ViewController1`.

Check that you don't have `@implementation`'s in the headers `#import`-ed by both of these files, *and* they don't both have `@implementation NSString(HTTPExtensions)` simultaneously.